# Javascript variable scope in anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I'm confused as to why the below will output "1".

If I use `var` to declare `a` in myFunc that should limit the scope of `a` to that function.

Calling "a" in the anonymous function (in the setInterval call) is a different function so why is that considered with the scope of myFunc?

Is it only because the function is anonymous? I would expect `a` to be available to another function unless `bind()` was used.

```
myFunc = function(){

    var a = 1;

    var int = setInterval(function () {

        console.log(a);

    }, 5);    

}
```

Comment: This is known as Closure. Here is the link to the doc :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: `var a` limits it to only this functional scope but the callback given to `setInterval` **is** in that functional scope.

Comment: Try to use LET instead of VAR here are some documentation about it https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/let

Answer (score 0):

The function bound to `setInterval` is a closure, when something is unknown in its own scope, it looks in the outer scope, in your case `myFunc` scope